# Is there a notion of discriminant in general systems of nonlinear algebraic equations?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-curves, nonlinear-system, discriminant

Given a system of nonlinear algebraic equations, is there a general way to define a discriminant? As far as I know you can define a discriminant in some cases, e.g. when you have elliptic equations and this is somehow related to the general theory of elliptic curves.

Is this only possible when you work case-by-case? Do there exist any theorems that render the construction of a discriminant impossible in some other cases?